# Invertible $ T \in L(R^n, R^n) $ such that there is no $S \in L(R^n,R^n)$ with $e^S = T.$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-transformations, inverse-function-theorem

I am having a hard time coming up with an example such that an invertible  $ T \in L(R^n, R^n)$ such that there is no $S \in L(R^n,R^n)$ with $e^S = T.$

Answer (score 1):

Any matrix $T$ with negative determinant will do, since you have
$$ \det (e^S) = e^{\text{tr}(S)}>0$$
This however is only because you require $S$ to be a real metrix. In the space of complex matrices you can always calculate $S=\ln T$ for invertible $T$.

Comment: what's an example of a matrix of $(R^n, R^n)$ with negative determinant?

Comment: @pop Take any matrix with a positive determinant. Multiply one row by $-1$. Done. For example $diag(-1,1,1,\dots,1)$.